# Rails error : "Unknown key: :dependant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When saving a form into database, I get the following error message : 
Unknown key: :dependant

I am not sure why

The model in question I try to save data to is called Museum. This model is lnked to another model called Exhibition.

Here are the two models :

```
class Museum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exhibitions, dependant: :destroy
end
```

and Exhibition model

```
class Exhibition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :museum
end
```

My Museum controller :

```
class MuseumsController < ApplicationController

def show
  @museum = Museum.find(params[:id])
  @museum.address = @museum.streetnumber + " " +    @museum.streetnumbercomplement + " " + @museum.street + " " + @museum.adresscomplement + "," + @museum.postalcode + " " + @museum.city + " " + @museum.citycomplement
end

def new
end

def create
  @museum = Museum.new(museum_params)
  @museum.save
  redirect_to @museum
end

private

def museum_params
  params.require(:museum).
    permit(:name,:streetnumber, :streetnumbercomplement,
      :street, :adresscomplement, :postalcode, :city,
      :description, :linktowebsite, :price, :citycomplement)
  end
end
```

I am building the two models controllers alltogether and have already added onto the Exhibiton tables some entries. Those entries have no reference to any Museum entry and the foreign key is probably not populated.
Should the problem of the Exhibiton entry not refering to any museums entry cause the problem ? 
In this case should my Rails application writing be more linear ?

(I'd like to mention that I am mimicking Getting Started tutorial and developping by trial and error. Hope no previous errors are not snowballing now..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible Typo:
dependant ---> dependent